# Screensaver stuck at "loading photos"

Tags: macos, mojave, screensaver

My MacBook Pro with Mojave sticks at "loading photos" when screensaver is activated or previewed.

I have reset SMC and NVRAM but did not help.

I have also removed `com.apple.screensaver*.plist` from the Library and Cache folder, but did not work either.

The non-photo screen savers work fine (such as Flurry, Shell ...)

But there is no problem if I login with another account(such as Guest).

If I start into Safe Mode, there is no photo screen savers.

How do I solve this annoying problem?

Console log:

```
Oct 18 15:45:55 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect.remoteservice[1833]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by com.apple.preference.desktopscre[1833]
Oct 18 15:45:55 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.auditd[2069]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.auditd
Oct 18 15:45:58 MacBook-Pro System Preferences[2078]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 18 15:45:58 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 18 15:46:00 MacBook-Pro com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect.remoteservice[2084]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 18 15:46:37 MacBook-Pro Activity Monitor[2091]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

**Update**

According to Buscar's suggestion, I am trying to reset permissions. But at step 7, I've got such an error message:

```
➜  ~ diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u` 
Ready to reset user permissions on disk1s1 Macintosh HD
Started verify/repair permissions on disk1s1 Macintosh HD
Some user permissions have been reset
Error: -69841: Permissions reset on user home directory failed
Underlying error: 1
```

The console log:

```
Oct 23 09:34:46 MacBook-Pro MDCrashReportTool[13104]: 13104:112717824|CrashReportCopierAFC.m:-[CrashReportCopierAFC copyAndProcessRemotePath:usingConnection:]| ERROR: Could not remove remote path at ./WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-10-18-2018__03:03:43.972.log
Oct 23 09:34:52 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[13109]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Oct 23 09:34:54 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.epson.pma.3732[13013]): Service exited due to SIGTERM | sent by killall[13112]
Oct 23 09:35:36 MacBook-Pro SecurityAgent[13118]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 23 09:37:13 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[13121]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Oct 23 09:39:15 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[13133]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Oct 23 09:42:49 MacBook-Pro syslogd[63]: ASL Sender Statistics
Oct 23 09:47:54 MacBook-Pro Terminal[13202]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 23 09:47:55 MacBook-Pro login[13205]: USER_PROCESS: 13205 ttys002
Oct 23 09:48:02 MacBook-Pro login[13205]: DEAD_PROCESS: 13205 ttys002
Oct 23 09:48:10 MacBook-Pro login[13279]: USER_PROCESS: 13279 ttys002
Oct 23 09:50:31 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.05000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000): Service only ran for 6 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 4 seconds.
Oct 23 09:52:48 MacBook-Pro com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[13412]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 23 09:52:50 MacBook-Pro syslogd[63]: ASL Sender Statistics
Oct 23 09:53:16 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking.5993C3CD-5AD9-417F-A8D7-86B4F38ADA5B[13418]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Oct 23 09:53:30 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
```

Even so I have restarted the computer, but the problem remains.

**Update 2**
Now I have successfully reset user permisions after executing `chflags -R nouchg ~` (found in the link from Buscar's). But the problem remains after restart the system:

```
Oct 23 21:38:29 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 23 21:38:33 MacBook-Pro SonyAutoLauncher[663]: Device path: (null)
Oct 23 21:38:33 MacBook-Pro SonyAutoLauncher[663]: Enum End!
Oct 23 21:38:34 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.503): Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.118" tried to register for endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" already registered by owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
Oct 23 21:38:50 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 23 21:38:50 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.503): com.apple.iBooksX.CacheDelete (lint): _AbandonCoalition is only available to Application services.
Oct 23 21:38:50 MacBook-Pro iTunesCacheExtension[899]: objc[899]: Class ITNSImage is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/iTunesLibrary (0x7fffab1dc568) and /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/PlugIns/iTunesCacheExtension.appex/Contents/MacOS/iTunesCacheExtension (0x1037be3f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 23 21:38:50 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 23 21:38:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 23 21:38:53 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.894): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
```

Comment: How many files are in the folder from which you are "loading photos"? If you have 20,000 or some such, the process can go glacial on you.

Comment: As a last resort, you can backup important files, and then reinstall MacOS X using bootcamp.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I have only one photo in that folder.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod Not an option.

Comment: @chance Well, that's not it then.

Comment: What is this ? `Error: -69841: Permissions reset on user home directory failed
Underlying error: 1`

Comment: Lets get ready for a surgery. Make a back up, create a USB both disk with Mojave. We might and hopefully not need them.

Comment: 1- can you deactivate or remove that `WiFi manager app` unless you must have it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You did well by testing with another user account.

So the problem is in your user account.

Not sure where but that does not matter right now

Lets start with easy step and repair your permissions.

[Follow the instructions from Apple.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538)

Lets see if that works, if not we will move to next step.

The `(com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect.remoteservice[1833]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by com.apple.preference.desktopscre[1833]` Sending the Kill (Sigkill) is not a good sign.

Comment: See my update please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where it would be "Loading Photos..." for a long time but would eventually come up. It ended up being tied to the albums or "moments" of the Photos App. It was resolved by creating a new empty system default photo library:

1. Backup all Photos libraries to external drive (for some reason moving to different location or renaming the library (located by default at ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary) did not help.
2. Delete them from the original location
3. disconnect the external drive
4. reopen the Photos app which should prompt for the creation of a new empty library
5. close and reopen the screen saver system preference

I didn't care for my previous Photos library so I can't tell if restoring them woule make the problem reoccur.